# Trace group of a skew group algebra of a commutative domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative noetherian domain that is also an algebra over a field $k$ Let $G$ is a finite group that acts on $R$ in a non-trivial way. Let $A=R*G$ be the skew group algebra of this action.

How can one compute the trace group (aka zeroth Hochschild homology group)
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A)=A/[A,A]
$$
of $A$?

The special case I'm mostly interested in is the following. Fix $k=\mathbb{C}$. Let $G \subset SL(V)$ be a finite subgroup and assume that $V$ is an irreducible complex representation of $G$. Let $R=S[V]$, where action of $G$ naturally extends to the symmetric algebra $S[V]$.

Answer (score 0):

Your special case is done in detail in

> Farinati, Marco Hochschild duality, localization, and smash products. J. Algebra 284 (2005), no. 1, 415–434.

You can check by hand that $A/[A,A]$ is the isomorphic to $(A/[R,A])_G$; here $A/[R,A]$ is a $G$-module in an obvious way, and $M_G$ denotes $M/(gm-m:g\in G,m\in M)$ for a $G$-module. This allows you do compute what you want in two steps: first look at $A/[R,A]$, and *then* take the coinvariants $(-)_G$ of the result.

Comment: Kernel of the canonical epimorphism $A/[R,A] \to A/[A,A]$ is generated by elements of the form $gx-xg$, $x \in A/[R,A]$, but kernel of the canonical epimorphism $A/[R,A] \to (A/[R,A])_G$ is generated by elements of the form $gx-x$, $x \in A/[R,A]$. Why they coincide? Is $xg-x \in [R,A]$?